# print wpf window after it has been totally rendered which event?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

how to a print wpf window after it has been totally rendered which event?

i have tried using loaded but some of the elements have not finished rendered yet

thanks

Answer (score 1):

[Read this article](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wpf/thread/0ca98da1-446f-4b2a-b2e9-bd9f2d8b3003) it shows you that there currently is no official way of getting notified of the end of the rendering but instead shows you a trick that you could use.

Answer (score 1):

I don't haev a proper solution for you, but you can make the following hack in the loaded event:

```
Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(delegate {      
        // here you are pretty shure that all rendering is done                
        // Put in your code here
        }), System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority.ContextIdle, null);
```

Probably it will also work with DispatcherPriority.Background, check it out.